# What happens to request in Web API controller when HttpClient times out?

Tags: c#, timeout, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to understand that what will happen to the request received by the Web API based service controller when the HttpClient that sent the request actually times out before the service can actually finish processing and send back response.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the `HttpClient` will close the underlying connection and throw a `TaskCancelledException`. That exceptions `StatusCode` will indicate there has been a timeout.

On the WebAPI side, on the other hand, will notice the clients disconnection and set it's  [`HttpResponse.ClientDisconnectedToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.clientdisconnectedtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) (which is of type `CancellationToken`) to cancelled. More on that [here](http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2014/06/27/ClientDisconnectsInASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

Comment: If the HttpClient does Timeout then it throws a TaskCancelledException

Comment: @DarrelMiller You're right. Mixed it up with `WebClient`. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Increase the value of the `HttpClient.Timeout` property.