# What happens to connection when a httpclient request times out?

Tags: .net-core, timeout, dotnet-httpclient, rate-limiting

I'm calling an API which has a rate limit on number of concurrent requests (e.g. 10).

Problem is when a request times out. From my end the request is complete and I can send a new one. But the server still treat the request as it is in progress and is included in the rate limit.

If I earlier was on the limit, my new request will now be rejected with a 429 response. I put my concurrency lower than the limit but multiple timeouts then cause the same problem.

[The not accepted response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445928/what-happens-to-request-in-web-api-controller-when-httpclient-times-out) says

> What happens is that the HttpClient will close the underlying connection and throw a TaskCancelledException

The question is old so I assume it is about .NetFramework and in .Net core it is more complicated since connections are pooled and reused.

So my questions are:

1. Will the connection be closed when there is a timeout in the HttpClient or is it just returned to the pool?
2. Will the server be informed when the connection is closed or is it some Garbage Collect process releasing abandoned connections on the server side (or is it implementation specific)?
3. Is there a way to avoid hitting the concurrent request limit after a timeout or is it just wait some time and retry?

Comment: How are you sending the concurrent requests?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan, Can you do that in different ways? I'm using `httpClient.PostAsync`